# Click to remove the highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below allows me to highlight text. Is there any way to remove the highlighted text (i.e. the text no longer is highlighted) by

1. clicking on the highlighted text then press "remove" button OR
2. double click on it?

I also want this highlighted text to be removed from element `highlights` as well.

```js
var lastSelection;
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {
  lastSelection = window.getSelection();
});
var highlights = document.createElement("div");

function getRightClick(e) {
  var rightclick;
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
  else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
  return rightclick; // true or false
}

function getSelectionCharacterOffsetsWithin(btnColor) {
  var selectedText = "null";
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selectedText = selection.toString();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    //Strip trailing punctation
    selectedText = selectedText.replace(/[\s.,!?:;'"-]+$/, "");
    //Leading space / quotes
    var offset = 0;
    var match = selectedText.match(/^[\s"']+/);
    if (match)
      offset = match[0].length;
    selectedText = selectedText.replace(/^[\s"']+/, "");
    if (selectedText === "") {
      alert("Error: you must select at least one character");
      tartOffset = 0, endOffset = 0, selectedText = "null";
    } else {
      var newInputid = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
      //This is code to keep word highlighted after selecting
      var newNode = document.createElement("span");
      newNode.classList.add('chosen');
      var previd = ("i" + newInputid);
      newNode.classList.add(previd);
      newNode.appendChild(range.extractContents());
      range.insertNode(newNode);
      var textSegment = $("." + previd);
      textSegment[0].style.backgroundColor = btnColor;
    }
  }
  return {
    text: selectedText,
    cid: previd
  };
}

$('.article').mousedown(function(event) {
  $('body').attr('mouse-top', event.clientY + window.pageYOffset);
  $('body').attr('mouse-left', event.clientX);

  if (!getRightClick(event)) {
    $('.entity_types').hide();
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }
});

$('.article').mouseup(function(event) {
  if (lastSelection.toString().length > 1 && !getRightClick(event)) {
    $('.entity_types').css({
      display: 'block',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: event.clientY + 15,
      left: event.clientX + 10
    });

    $('.entity_types button').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var btnColor = $(this)[0].style.color;
      var selOffsets = getSelectionCharacterOffsetsWithin(btnColor);
      var selectedText = selOffsets.text;
      var selectedID = selOffsets.cid
      var txt = document.createTextNode(selectedText);
      highlights.appendChild(txt);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='entity_class' class="entity_types">
  <button class="btn" style="color:green">Class 1</button>
  <button class="btn" style="color:red">Class 2</button>
  <button class="btn" style="color:purple">Class 3</button>
</div>

<div class="article" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  What is missing from this statement, and likely to be asked by lawmakers, is why it took a newspaper to discover this breach of Facebook's systems. And, once Facebook knew, why it didn't notify the public and regulators immediately - instead of doing
  everything it could to block the story.
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML this code is acting on, in a [mcve].

Comment: I also converted it to a snippet for you, just keep the reference to jQuery and add your HTML.

Comment: when you create the highlighted span can't you just bind to it's click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using event delegation, this will clear on double click all `span` with the `.chosen` class:

```
$('.article').on('dblclick', '.chosen', function() {
  (this).replaceWith(this.innerText);
});
```

Example:

```js
var lastSelection;
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {
  lastSelection = window.getSelection();
});
var highlights = document.getElementById("highlights");

function getRightClick(e) {
  var rightclick;
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
  else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
  return rightclick; // true or false
}

function getSelectionCharacterOffsetsWithin(btnColor) {
  var selectedText = "null";
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selectedText = selection.toString();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    //Strip trailing punctation
    selectedText = selectedText.replace(/[\s.,!?:;'"-]+$/, "");
    //Leading space / quotes
    var offset = 0;
    var match = selectedText.match(/^[\s"']+/);
    if (match)
      offset = match[0].length;
    selectedText = selectedText.replace(/^[\s"']+/, "");
    if (selectedText === "") {
      alert("Error: you must select at least one character");
      tartOffset = 0, endOffset = 0, selectedText = "null";
    } else {
      var newInputid = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
      //This is code to keep word highlighted after selecting
      var newNode = document.createElement("span");
      newNode.classList.add('chosen');
      var previd = ("i" + newInputid);
      newNode.setAttribute('data-cid', previd);
      newNode.appendChild(range.extractContents());
      newNode.style.backgroundColor = btnColor;
      range.insertNode(newNode);
    }
  }
  return {
    text: selectedText,
    cid: previd
  };
}

$('.article').mousedown(function(event) {
  $('body').attr('mouse-top', event.clientY + window.pageYOffset);
  $('body').attr('mouse-left', event.clientX);

  if (!getRightClick(event)) {
    $('.entity_types').hide();
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }
});

$('.article').mouseup(function(event) {
  if (lastSelection.toString().length > 1 && !getRightClick(event)) {
    $('.entity_types').css({
      display: 'block',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: event.clientY + 15,
      left: event.clientX + 10
    });
  }
});

$('.entity_types button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var btnColor = $(this)[0].style.color;
  var selOffsets = getSelectionCharacterOffsetsWithin(btnColor);
  var selectedText = selOffsets.text;
  var selectedID = selOffsets.cid
  var txt = document.createTextNode(selectedText);
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.appendChild(txt);
  span.setAttribute('data-cid', selectedID);
  span.classList.add('highlighted');
  highlights.appendChild(span);
});

$('.article').on('dblclick', '.chosen', function() {
  var cid = this.getAttribute('data-cid');
  highlights.querySelector('[data-cid=' + cid + ']').remove();
  (this).replaceWith(this.innerText);
});
```

```css
.highlighted:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='entity_class' class="entity_types">
  <button class="btn" style="color:green">Class 1</button>
  <button class="btn" style="color:red">Class 2</button>
  <button class="btn" style="color:purple">Class 3</button>
</div>

<div class="article" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  What is missing from this statement, and likely to be asked by lawmakers, is why it took a newspaper to discover this breach of Facebook's systems. And, once Facebook knew, why it didn't notify the public and regulators immediately - instead of doing
  everything it could to block the story.
</div>

<br>

<div id="highlights"></div>
```

Comment: Aha that's a lot simpler than I thought, thanks so much Ori! Does this make sure the unhighlighted text is removed from variable `highlights` as well, where it was previously added as a TextNode ?

Comment: Nope it doesn't. What are you using `highlights` for?

Comment: There is a div dedicated for displaying the highlighted text by `var show_highlights = document.getElementById("show_highlights"); show_highlights.appendChild(highlights.childNodes[i])`

Comment: Instead of adding the txt to the div (which will be harder to find if there are duplicates), clone  the `newNode` span and add it to `highlight`, or at least create an element with the same selectionID (that should be a data-* instead of class). Now you can remove it by the selectionID.

Comment: Thanks Ori! Sorry I am confused. Do you mean `$("show_highlights").data("id", selectedID); $("show_highlights").data("text", selectedText)` and then what to do? Sorry I am a newbie to JS.

Comment: `.data()` is a jquery way of adding data to DOM nodes. Since you're mixing JS DOM manipulation with jquery, I wouldn't go that way. Use `.setAttribute()` to add a `data-cid` tag. I've updated the demo to do that. You can see the contents of highlight on add and removing items.

Comment: I've also moved `$('.entity_types button').on('click', function(e) {` outside of the `$('.article').mouseup(function(event) ` event handler to prevent add the click handler multiple times to each button.

Comment: That is a beautiful solution! Thanks very much Ori! Would you be so kind to answer my question below please? I have tried but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: You're welcome. Before you move forward, you need to make your code more unified. You should refactor everything either to jQuery DOM handling or the native DOM apis. In addition post your question as a new question instead of an answer.

Comment: Thanks Ori! I have made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755029/click-to-display-highlighted-text