# Click to display highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to have a "show highlights" button that displays all highlighted text in the article. I have managed to get everything else working apart from the the "show highlights" button itself. Basically, `highlights` needs to add to `selected_highlights` which allows to be displayed by clicking the button.

I should refactor everything either to jQuery DOM handling or the native DOM apis, and so it doesn't mess up the "remove highlights" function, but I am struggling to make everything work.

```js
var lastSelection;
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {
  lastSelection = window.getSelection();
});
var showBtn = document.getElementById('show_highlights_btn');
//var highlights = document.getElementById("highlights");
var highlights = document.createElement('div');

function getRightClick(e) {
  var rightclick;
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
  else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
  return rightclick; // true or false
}

function br() {
  return document.createElement('br');
}

function getSelectionCharacterOffsetsWithin(btnColor) {
  var selectedText = "null";
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selectedText = selection.toString();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    //Strip trailing punctation
    selectedText = selectedText.replace(/[\s.,!?:;'"-]+$/, "");
    //Leading space / quotes
    var offset = 0;
    var match = selectedText.match(/^[\s"']+/);
    if (match)
      offset = match[0].length;
    selectedText = selectedText.replace(/^[\s"']+/, "");
    if (selectedText === "") {
      alert("Error: you must select at least one character");
      tartOffset = 0, endOffset = 0, selectedText = "null";
    } else {
      var newInputid = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
      //This is code to keep word highlighted after selecting
      var newNode = document.createElement("span");
      newNode.classList.add('chosen');
      var previd = ("i" + newInputid);
      newNode.setAttribute('data-cid', previd);
      newNode.appendChild(range.extractContents());
      newNode.style.backgroundColor = btnColor;
      range.insertNode(newNode);
    }
  }
  return {
    text: selectedText,
    cid: previd
  };
}

$('.article').mousedown(function(event) {
  $('body').attr('mouse-top', event.clientY + window.pageYOffset);
  $('body').attr('mouse-left', event.clientX);

  if (!getRightClick(event)) {
    $('.entity_types').hide();
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }
});

$('.article').mouseup(function(event) {
  if (lastSelection.toString().length > 1 && !getRightClick(event)) {
    $('.entity_types').css({
      display: 'block',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: event.clientY + 15,
      left: event.clientX + 10
    });
  }
});

$('.entity_types button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var btnColor = $(this)[0].style.color;
  var selOffsets = getSelectionCharacterOffsetsWithin(btnColor);
  var selectedText = selOffsets.text;
  var selectedID = selOffsets.cid
  var txt = document.createTextNode(selectedText);
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.appendChild(txt);
  span.setAttribute('data-cid', selectedID);
  span.classList.add('highlighted');
  highlights.appendChild(span);
});

showBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log("display button");
  var selected_highlights = document.getElementById("highlights");

  /** first remove current text **/
  while (selected_highlights.hasChildNodes()) {
    selected_highlights.removeChild(selected_highlights.lastChild);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < highlights.innerHTML.length; i++) {
    console.log('display highlight');
    selected_highlights.appendChild(highlights.childNodes[i]);
    selected_highlights.appendChild(br());
  }
});

$('.article').on('dblclick', '.chosen', function() {
  var cid = this.getAttribute('data-cid');
  highlights.querySelector('[data-cid=' + cid + ']').remove();
  (this).replaceWith(this.innerText);
});
```

```css
.highlighted:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='entity_class' class="entity_types">
  <button class="btn" style="color:green">Class 1</button>
  <button class="btn" style="color:red">Class 2</button>
  <button class="btn" style="color:purple">Class 3</button>
</div>

<div class="article" style="overflow-x:auto;">
  What is missing from this statement, and likely to be asked by lawmakers, is why it took a newspaper to discover this breach of Facebook's systems. And, once Facebook knew, why it didn't notify the public and regulators immediately - instead of doing
  everything it could to block the story.
</div>

<br>

<button id="show_highlights_btn"  type="button">Show highlights</button>
<div id="highlights"></div>
```

Comment: what does this line is supposed to do: `selected_highlights.appendChild(br());`  where is the function called `br()` ?

Comment: Oh my bad, I have added `br()` in the question now. It adds a newline between every two highlights to be displayed.

Comment: Hi is this code wrapped in $( document ).ready or is it missing only in your snippet?

Comment: It doesn't have `$( document ).ready`. The JS code is wrapped in `require(['jquery-noconflict'], function(jQuery){...}`, if that's what you want to know.